# How do I get past BusyBox?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, initramfs, busybox

I have a problem with my Ubuntu installation. When I go to start Ubuntu from UEFI, I get the purple screen and choose Ubuntu (as normal), but then I am greeted with BusyBox and it won't let me get to Ubuntu for some reason.

BusyBox Output:

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of commands.

(initramfs) [    7.474227] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   7.474295] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I am running Ubuntu from a flashdrive, and I am running the flash drive not directly from a computer port anymore, but from a USB extender because the USB ports messed up (I don't know how), and only one USB port it working. I checked in Windows if the flash drive is detected from the extender, and it is. Also in BusyBox, I don't have the `fdisk` command in `/sbin`, and I don't have a `/mnt` folder.

How should I fix this?

Comment: "I am running Ubuntu from a flashdrive" is problem #1. At the busybox prompt, type `fsck -f /` (you may have to type `exit` and then `fsck -f /`). Report back.

Comment: BusyBox can occur when trying to use a persistent partition with a syslinux boot, such as UNetbootin makes, try a grub2 booter like mkusb makes.

Comment: @heynnema the computer works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: @user189452 glad it's working for you! I'll put that into a quick answer, and maybe you can accept it for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

re:  *I get the purple screen and choose Ubuntu (as normal), but then I am greeted with BusyBox and it won't let me get to Ubuntu for some reason.*

At the busybox prompt, type `fsck -f /` (*you may have to type `exit` and then `fsck -f /`*) to fix any file system corruption.

Comment: FSCK also worked for me, thanks!  I was running Kubuntu 20.04 from the hard disk.  I attempted to run FSCK at the prompt but failed.  After reading up on FSCK at https://linuxhandbook.com/fsck-command/ I ended up booting to a live USB and running "sudo fsck /dev/sda3" from a terminal window.