# How do I get pass of ubuntu busybox 1.30.1

Tags: boot, do-release-upgrade

I'm using ubuntu 19.04 but yesterday, I got a message about the release of ubuntu 20.04 from software updater l. So, today I started the process. First of all, it was okay. But at installing upgrades part, It got error and process got stopped. So, I reboot the computer. After showing ubuntu logo, I got into the busyboxv1.30.1. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system & `fsck` your system (ie. file-system check). Your system though should have upgraded to 19.10 (not 20.04) so something was wrong with your details (are you on 19.04? as it's EOL/unsupported) which makes me reluctant to provide details as something doesn't add up. Had you fudged your system somehow?  Was your EOL system up-to-date before upgrade? or were you actually already using 19.10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get past BusyBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943661/how-do-i-get-past-busybox)